# Renamed a project in my Eclipse workspace via the filesystem and now cannot open it.

Tags: java, eclipse

I had a folder that I downloaded from GitHub which is a group project for college. I worked on it a bunch and added tons of code and then planned to reupload this big folder straight back up to GitHub (yeah, worst version control in the world I know). We were just incrementing the project folders by 1 each time so I renamed the folder in my Eclipse workspace to Project3. I then tried to reopen this folder in Eclipse and every time I selected it nothing happens. It has me very worried. Luckily most of my code was in a class file which I am still able to access however there are some changes here and there in other files that I made which ideally I would like back. Any idea what I should do to be able to open this project up in Eclipse again? I should also note that I tried renaming it back to the original name.

Comment: Where did you rename it, within the Eclipse app or on the file system?   All Eclipse workspaces are just local directories so you can go there to find your code.

Also, using "team" functionality and proper use of git within Eclipse will avoid all of the problems you face - lost code, renamed directories, failure to keep track of incremental changes, etc.  You just branch and work and then push and do a pull-request when done.

Comment: @SteveHarris I renamed it by going to the workspace folder in Windows explorer and renaming it there.

Comment: @SteveHarris In the file system, yeah.

Comment: @WewLad - you should be able to just import the project from the renamed folder directory.   Eclipse is just a window into files on the filesystem so unless you deleted it, you probably still have it.

Comment: @SteveHarris @ PratikAmbani I tried creating a new workspace and moved it there. Initially I thought it worked however when I compile it, I get the GUI I made and everything however a lot of my folders such as src, default package and 4 of my class files show error signs on them. The file structure of the project also feels different. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/eu0k5. The error I get when I compile is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptions:org:sqlite:jbdc.

Comment: You need to "Import" the project.  However, now that the settings and project files have been mangled, you'll want to "import" it as a Java project and hope for the best.  Worst case you may need to reconstruct your Build path after importing.

Before importing move it out of the workspaces and you'll probably want to delete .settings and .project also.  Google the processes for importing projects - there are all kinds of things you can do including importing from GitHub directly into a local repo (for future reference).

Comment: @SteveHarris What so I select when importing it? Nothing comes up when I search Java.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfMeSelppuc

Comment: @SteveHarris I'll watch that, thanks for the help. What is the safest way to rename a project in future?

Comment: Don't do that.  Use GitHub properly :-)